# What does "LESS" - the "dynamic stylesheet language" stand for?

Tags: less

What does "**LESS**" - the "dynamic stylesheet language" stand for?

for e.g CSS stands for "Cascading Style Sheets"

Comment: Does it *have* to be an acronym for something? Why? Maybe it's simply because you have to write *less* CSS?

Comment: Its Less, not LESS ....

Comment: Was confused if its an acronym or not...

Answer (score 1):

LESS stands for Leaner CSS

[Source:](http://usabilitypost.com/2009/06/16/introducing-less-a-better-css/)

Comment: I think it's probably also a pun with writing *less* code :)